# Packaging an app in docker that can be configured at run time

Tags: docker

I have packaged a web app I've been working on as a docker image.

I want to be able to start the image with some configuration, like this is the url of the couchdb server to use, etc.

What is the best way of supplying configuration? My app relies on env variables can I set these at run time?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In addition to setting environment variables during `docker run` (using `-e`/`--env` and `--env-file`) as you already discovered, there are other options available:

- Using `--link` to link your container to (for instance) your couchdb server. This will work if your server is also a container (or if you use an [ambassador container](https://docs.docker.com/articles/ambassador_pattern_linking/) to another server). Linking containers will make some environment variables available, including server IP and port, that your script can use. This will work if you only need to set references to services.
- [Using volumes](https://docs.docker.com/userguide/dockervolumes/). Volumes defined in the Dockerfile can be mapped to host folders, so you can use them to access configuration files, for instance. This is useful for very complex configurations.
- Extending the image. You can create a new image based on your original and `ADD` custom configuration files or `ENV` entries. This is the least flexible option but is useful in complex configuration to simplify the launching, specially when the configuration is mostly static (probably a bad idea for services/hostnames, but can work for frameworks that can be configured differently for dev/production). Can be combined with any of the above.

Answer (score 2):

It seems docker supports setting env variables - should have read the manual!

`docker run -e MYVAR1 --env MYVAR2=foo --env-file ./env.list ubuntu bash`

http://docs.docker.com/reference/commandline/cli/#run